# Strange behavior when file name is prefixed with space in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>touch " t.txt"
```

The above will create `t.txt` under `C:\` ,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug in whoever's touch script/exe you are using? Touch is not part of Windows.

Martyn

Comment: you can reproduce with what ever other editor you prefer too.

Comment: The first editor I tried (notepad) was able to successfully safe " t.txt" in my documents without problems when I surrounded the filename with quotes in the save-as dialog.

Comment: Of course, because \ is the name of the root directory. \foo would save foo in the root too.